# Google Cloud datastore : Use the cursor in a reverse query

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

> [Documentation > Datastore Queries > Limitations of cursors](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries?hl=en#limitations_of_cursors)
>
> - sort order
>
>   An exception is if the original query's final sort order was on `__key__`. In that case, you can use the cursor in a reverse query, which is the original query with each sort order reversed. The reverse query can modify the start cursor, end cursor, offset, and limit.

Although it is stated that only __key__ can be used in the reverse order, it seems that it is also available in  another property that created custom index. I tried it both in development environment and production environment.

What mean "An exception is if the original query's final sort order was on __key__." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify this with a simple example:

Let's say you have a query (omitting cursor/limit syntax) -

```
SELECT * FROM MyEntity ORDER BY PROP1 ASC
```

Now the requirement is that you need to traverse both in forward and reverse directions and using cursors.

The first thing you need to do is to modify your query to have `__key__` as the last sort -

```
SELECT * FROM Entity ORDER BY PROP1 ASC, __key__ ASC
```

You can traverse forward normally using cursors, but when you need to traverse backwards, you need to execute the query by reversing the sort order. You can still use the same cursor of the page you are on. So, the query will change to

```
SELECT * FROM Entity ORDER BY PROP1 DESC, __key__ DESC
```

Notice that we have changed **ASC**endng order to **DESC**ending.

This would essentially give you the previous records from the current cursor location. In order for this to work, you need to have appropriate composite indexes (for example one on `PROP1` and `__key__` in DESC order). Of course you can also add other properties to the sort order, or remove `PROP1` from the example, if you are fine with the results sorted just by key.

With out **key** as the last sort, you won't be able use the cursor you got when going forward in a reverse order query. That's what that "Exception" rule is.

Comment: Thanks!   For queries that do not use __key__ in sort order,  can retrieve data only once with DESC  using the cursor obtained in ASC ?

Comment: Without the key as the last (or only) sort, when you switch the sort order would result in incorrect results.